# Setup New Wordpress site on subdomain first or completely different domain?

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

I have a client wanting me to create a whole new WP site for them but with most of the same content as their current WP site.

Would it be easier for me to setup a subdomain on their current domain (i.e. test.theirdomain.com) and install a fresh wordpress on it and then move it over to the main domain, or create the site using a completely different domain and then move it to their domain once it's completed? I've never had to move a WP site to a different domain so I don't know all of the headaches that come with it. I figured asking prior to diving in was my best option.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a standard WordPress site isn't really a problem, you have to change the hostname a couple times in the database.

Moving a WordPress MU site is a relative nightmare, here be dragons.

Answer (score 1):

It's 6 vs (2x3). It's just as easy to do either. Just as easy if you appreciate the problems that you encounter moving WordPress sites (normals ones I'm talking about, not MU/Network). I wrote some info in this post;

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11371308/creating-a-wordpress-dev-enviornment-and-uploading-to-production/11376492#11376492

It will save you a lot of time if you are doing WP work.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how dynamic the website is, the easiest way is to create another site (domain doesn't matter) get it how you like. Then when you have it to your preference, change your DNS entries and web server to use the new site. Or you could even change your local DNS entries to point the domain to your new website so when you're ready, all you have to do is change your authoritative DNS to your new webserver.